# Integration testing framework for applications written in multiple languages

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, database-testing

Query already asked at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499746/multi-language-integration-testing-framework)

For an enterprise application with huge source code repository which is written in C/C++/Java/JavaScript, for performance reasons. Application also uses relational Database mysql & key-value berkeley DB to store relevant data for the application.

We could use unit testing frameworks like `JUnit` for java & [Check](http://check.sourceforge.net/) for C in such large applications.

My question:

But, I would like to understand, How would one think of designing Integration testing framework for such Enterprise applications?

Comment: By "integration testing" I assume you mean end-to-end with all the bells and whistles (including database access and the likes)?

Comment: @nablex Yes including the database.

Comment: I have added an answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499746/multi-language-integration-testing-framework/. Always interested in feedback! :)

Answer (score 0):

If DB access is in Java, I would suggest to take a look at http://acolyte.eu.org/ which makes possible JDBC unit testing.

It allows to instantiate connection managed by handler you define, to return this or that result according query or update executed.